# Flex dropdownlist not displaying items

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

The application I'm working on has several spark dropdownlists. If the list is too long and a scroller appears then "holes" appear in the list. Scrolling up and down with the scroll bar or arrows does nothing other than normal scrolling, but scrolling with a mouse wheel fixes the problem.

[Image of an open drop down with holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GaZg.png)

The code for the dropdownlist itself is:

```
<s:DropDownList id="yearCombo" dataProvider="{yearDataPro}" change="getAllTicketsInYear()" width="100%" selectedIndex="{selectedYear}" chromeColor="0xFFFFFF"/>
```

The end result is that yearDataPro is an array of strings from "2006" to "2015" as of right now.

Comment: I think you have problem with rendered data provider. Post your object and dropdownlist

Comment: That bit I figured out, just not sure why it isn't rendering properly. I'm using the default skin. I have added the code to the original post.